# Updating user balance method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, methods

In the code below, I am trying to add or subtract user bets (e.g. $10) and update the balance amount. Initially, the balance will start at $100 and as the user continues to make bets, the balance will update until the balance reaches $0 or the user decides to quit.

The code below works correctly on the first bet but the balance doesn't update during the second bet. Any help would be appreciated!

```
int balance = 100; 

    protected int PlayerBalance()
    {

        int totalBalance = 0;
        if (CalculateWinAmount() > 0) //CalculateWinAmount() method returns the win amount. If no wins, the method return 0
        {
            totalBalance += CalculateWinAmount();
        }
        else
        {
            totalBalance -= BetAmount(); //BetAmount() method returns the amount the user has bet (e.g. $5, $10..)
        }          
        return totalBalance += balance;
    }
    protected void DisplayPlayerBalance()
    {
        playerTotalAmountLabel.Text = PlayerBalance().ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting your balance correctly as @Mattew has already specified in his answer.

As part of refactoring, you do not need local variable `totalBalance` as you can directly operate on `balance`. And you should not call `CalculateWinAmount` two time for performance reason.

**Refactored Code :**

```
        static int balance = 100;
        protected int PlayerBalance()
        {
            int winAmount = CalculateWinAmount();//CalculateWinAmount() method returns the win amount. If no wins, the method return 0
            if (winAmount > 0) 
            {
                balance += winAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                int betAmount = BetAmount();
                balance -= betAmount; //BetAmount() method returns the amount the user has bet (e.g. $5, $10..)
            }
            return balance;
        }
        protected void DisplayPlayerBalance()
        {
            playerTotalAmountLabel.Text = PlayerBalance().ToString();
        }
```

Comment: It still resets the balance at $100 before each bet. For instance, in your first bet if you bet $5 and you lose, the balance will be updated to $95. However, if you bet $5 again and you lose, the balance gets updated to $95 instead of $90.

Comment: As balance is instance field which intialize to 100 each time when instance is created. You should define `balance` variable as static which intialize only once.

Comment: Thank you, Akash. Static was the keyword I was missing all along. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not setting the balance:  Try the following

```
int balance = 100; 

protected int PlayerBalance()
{

    int totalBalance = 0;
    if (CalculateWinAmount() > 0) //CalculateWinAmount() method returns the win amount. If no wins, the method return 0
    {
        totalBalance += CalculateWinAmount();
    }
    else
    {
        totalBalance -= BetAmount(); //BetAmount() method returns the amount the user has bet (e.g. $5, $10..)
    }          
    // Set the balance to the current balance + the new totalbalance
    balance += totalBalance;

    // return the balance figure
    return balance;
}
protected void DisplayPlayerBalance()
{
    playerTotalAmountLabel.Text = PlayerBalance().ToString();
}
```

Comment: It still resets the balance at $100 before each bet. For instance, in your first bet you bet $5 and you lose, the balance will be updated to $95. However, if you bet $5 again and you lose, the balance gets updated to $95 instead of $90.

Comment: It shouldn't be resetting the balance to 100 again unless you are re-running the first line setting the balance to 100.  If you just run the PlayerBalance() function it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You never updated the *balance* field in the *PlayerBalance* method.

Instead of a using the local variable *totalBalance*, I would recommend simply updating the balance as follows:

```
protected int PlayerBalance()
{
    if (CalculateWinAmount() > 0) //CalculateWinAmount() method returns the win amount. If no wins, the method return 0
    {
        balance += CalculateWinAmount();
    }
    else
    {
        balance -= BetAmount(); //BetAmount() method returns the amount the user has bet (e.g. $5, $10..)
    }          
    return balance;
}
```